# How can I list transitive packages for a C#.NET project with traceability?

Tags: nuget

To list packages for a project with transitive packages, I do:

```
dotnet list package --include-transitive
```

, but this doesn't show me which transitive package came from which package.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11625